# type 'List<FlashcardsList>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Back>' how to fix this?

Tags: android, list, flutter, dart, mobile

Good day, I just want to ask because I don't know what this means? I am aiming to make a card that will produce sounds on both cards the front and back. I changed the list file on my flutter to the way I think I know. I extended the Back class to the FlashcardList class. and I added a list of my back class for the back picture, and  I changed my back picture to the list of Back class.

This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:assets_audio_player/assets_audio_player.dart';
import 'package:baybay_app/FlashCards/FlashcardsList.dart';
import 'package:flip_card/flip_card.dart';

class Flashcards extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<FlashcardsList> _flashCardsList = flashcardsList;
  final List<Back>_back = back;
  @override
  _FlashcardsState createState() => _FlashcardsState();
}

class _FlashcardsState extends State<Flashcards> {
  GlobalKey<FlipCardState> cardKey = GlobalKey<FlipCardState>();
  CarouselController buttonCarouselController = CarouselController();
  List<FlashcardsList> flashCardsList;
  List<Back> back;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    flashCardsList = widget._flashCardsList;
    back = widget._back;
  }Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Sample Carousel')),
    body: Column(children: <Widget>[
      CarouselSlider.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return     FlipCard(
                  front: ListTile(
                    onLongPress: () {
                      onPlayAudio(index);
                    },
                    title: Container(
                      child: Image(
                          image: AssetImage(
                              widget._flashCardsList[index].pictures1)),
                    ),

                  ),
                  back: ListTile(
                      title: Container(
                        child: Image(
                            image: AssetImage(
                                widget._back[index].pictures1)),
                      ),
                    ),


          );
        },
        itemCount: widget._flashCardsList.length,
        options: CarouselOptions(
          autoPlay: false,
          enlargeCenterPage: true,
          viewportFraction: 0.9,

          initialPage: 2,
        ),
      ),
    ]),
  );
  void onPlayAudio(index) async{
    AssetsAudioPlayer assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();
    assetsAudioPlayer.open(
        Audio(widget._flashCardsList[index].sound1)
    );
  }
  void PlayAudio(index) async{
    AssetsAudioPlayer assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();
    assetsAudioPlayer.open(
        Audio(widget._flashCardsList[index].sound2)
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my list file:

```
import 'package:assets_audio_player/assets_audio_player.dart';
class FlashcardsList{
  final String pictures1;
  final String name;
  final String sound1;
  final String pictures2;
  final String sound2;
  FlashcardsList({
    this.pictures1,
    this.name,
    this.sound1,
    this.pictures2,
    this.sound2
  });
// ignore: empty_constructor_bodies
}

final flashcardsList = [
  FlashcardsList(
    pictures1: 'assets/Ba.PNG',
    name: 'Ba',
    sound1: 'audioAssets/Ba.mp3',

  ),
  FlashcardsList(
    pictures1: 'assets/KA.PNG',
    name: 'Ka',
    sound1: 'audioAssets/Ka.mp3',

  ),
  FlashcardsList(
      pictures1: 'assets/KA.PNG',
      name: 'Ka',
      sound1: 'audioAssets/Ka.mp3',

  )

];

FlashcardsList instance = FlashcardsList(pictures1:'assets/Ba,PNG', name: 'Ba', sound1:'assets/Think of Me Instrumental (1).mp3');

class Back extends FlashcardsList{
  String picture2;
  String Sound2;
  Back({
    this.picture2,
    this.Sound2
  });
}

final back = [
  FlashcardsList(pictures1: 'assets/A.PNG',
      sound1: 'audioAssets/La.mp3'),

];
```

I'm new to flutter btw. Thank you and please help me!

Comment: Your naming style is super confusing. Things are named "list" that aren't a list, things are named with plural even though they are only a single element, variables are numbered for no good reason. If your naming is confusing, it's often a sign that you are confused about what those things do. Maybe your confusion clears up when you try to find proper names for your variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always good practice to highlight the line throwing the error

The error message means that you assign a list (array) of type (class) FlashcardList to an object that expects a list of type Back. So you have to work on the type mismatch

Answer (score 0):

Well the issue is in your list file this part of the code:

```
final back = [
  FlashcardsList(pictures1: 'assets/A.PNG',
      sound1: 'audioAssets/La.mp3'),
];
```

You are assigning an item of type Flashcard to the back array which you specified should be an array of items of type Back.
Changing Flashcards to Back will solve the issue.